# Import project to another workspace including run configurations

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm moving a bunch of projects from one workspace to another. 
Each of the projects had a main() function, which was called with some default arguments that was part of the Run configuration for that project.

When I import these projects, it looks like these run configurations are not copied. I need to specify the input arguments etc again - Run as  -> Run Configurations -> update stuff .

Is there a way to copy them over also?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fwizards%2Fref-export_launch_configs.htm

Comment: this is still done on a per project basis right?  So I guess I need to import run configs for each project one by one

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easier way, but if you find all the file named *.launch - that will give you the list, then just copy those files.  We actually save the base set of launch files we use as part of our project so that they are part of the project.  For launches created on-the-fly, you will find those in the workspace.

Comment: I hadn't saved the launch configurations so i guess i'll have to do this manually

Answer (score 1):

Open the menu "Run -> Run configurations ..." and select the Launch configuration you want to share inside your project. Goto the common tab inside the selected launch and there you can specify a "Save as" location via "Shared file:". As location select your project. So then an appropriate ".launch" file is created and can be checked in or exported with the project itself.